# sync_binlog=0 affects performance，but sync_binlog=1 works well

Tags: mysql

right now I found some strange things in one MySQL instance .

backgroup
we use SSD to store datafile , but the binlog files are stored in the SAS disk 
sync_binlog=0
TPS 4000 insert+update per second
max_binlog_size 500M

when MySQL creates new binlog file , we found that some transcations commit statement would be written into slow.log

and when I set sync_binlog 0->2000->1000->200->100 . 
Finally , when  the sync_binlog=0 ,  the commit statement disappear in the slow.log .

Hope for you help . I am really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is straight forward.
when you were using sync_binlog=1 then what was happening is like the logs are also being written to the disk without using the file system support.But only the comitted transactions were going into the logs.
but now you'hv turned up `sync_binlog=0`, which means you don't want to keep a record of the comitted transactions on the disk means you are relying on to the operating system's file system.
So, if your autocommit is off then you will only get the comitted transactions in the logs else all the transactions(whether they are committed or not) will go into the logs.

so there is a possibility that you might be using mysql with autocommit 'on' and all the transactions are going into the logs and you are only going onto the transactions that are slow and not commmitted.

hope this will help